# Como adicionar valores de uma StringList em um PSafeArray

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou precisando pegar os valores que estão armazenados em uma TStringList e adicionar esses valores em PSafeArray, que mais tarde serão enviados como parâmetros para uma dll.

Já tentei de varias formas, porém todas sem sucesso.

Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de várias consultas consegui fazer o que precisava.

Abaixo como fazer o preenchimento dele, como também a leitura:

```
procedure TForm1.TratarSafeArray(Lista: TStringList);
var
  VSafeArry : psafearray ;
  saBound :  TSafeArrayBound;
  Index : array [0..0] of LongInt ;// 1 dimension
  Valor : wideString;

  LBound, UBound, I: LongInt;
  W: WideString;


begin

  Memo2.Clear;

  //Gravando dados PSafeArray
  saBound.lLbound := 0 ;
  saBound.cElements := Lista.Count;

  VSafeArry := SafeArrayCreate (VT_BSTR , 1 , saBound) ;
  if VSafeArry = nil then begin
    Exit;
  end;

  for i := 0 to Lista.Count -1 do begin
    Index[0] := i;
    Valor := Lista[i];
    SafeArrayPutElement(VSafeArry, index, Pchar(Valor)^);
  end;

  //Lendo dados do PSafeArray
  SafeArrayGetLBound(VSafeArry, 1, LBound);
  SafeArrayGetUBound(VSafeArry, 1, UBound);

  for I := LBound to UBound do begin
    SafeArrayGetElement(VSafeArry, I, W);
    memo2.Lines.add(UpperCase(W));
  end;

  SafeArrayDestroy(VSafeArry);

end;
```